# Animate UIView frame with CALayer as subview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-animation, calayer

**What I have:**

I have a a hierarchy of `UIView's` and a `CAGradientLayer` that I use to set the "background colour" of this hierarchy. So I have something like this:

ViewA -> ViewB -> CAGradientLayer

**What I am doing:**

At one point, I want to animate the `frame` (only the height of it) of the ViewA. So it would be something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:timeInterval
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                              viewA.frame = newFrame;
}];
```

**The issue:**

The problem with this is that the `CAGradientLayer` won't animate it's frame, it simply change it's frame, and then the viewA starts animating as intended (this is clearly visible by setting the simulator to slow-motion animations).

**What I tried:**

I tried to do what Apple recommends [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1620/_index.html), by doing it inside the `UIView` animation block, but it didn't actually work, because I am still animating the frame here:

```
viewA.frame = newFrame;
```

I also understand that the I should animate the bounds, and not the frame of the `CALayer`, the problem is that, how can I animate the bounds and when animating the frame of the ViewA leave that `CALayer` out of the animation?

**What I want:**

I just want to animate the change of its height, so I would see both the `viewA` and the `CAGradientLayer` animating at the same time.

Comment: couldn't you set an UIImageView(with a gradient UIImage) as a subview of ViewB instead of a CAGradientLayer? It should resize at the same time. Hope it helps, but it's only an idea cos I don't know the behavior of a CAGradientLayer when resizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW17).

Try encapsulating your view animation code along with layer animation explicitly. Do not expect layer to animate automatically. Since you are dealing with positioning, you would need to change `graidentlayer.bounds`.

If that does not work, try this before your animation code:

```
[CATransaction begin];    
[CATransaction setDisableActions: NO];    
[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to understand that the `UIView` and `CALayer` hierarchy are different. Layout changes and animations operating on a `UIView` will not automatically affect the `CALayer` hierarchy.

So if you want changes applied to your view affect a layer you'll have to update that yourself.

Your code is also missing details. For example you claim you see your gradient layer change it's frame, but you don't show where you are changing it. Did you overwrite `layoutSubviews` somewhere to update it's `frame`?

By default updating a layer `frame` will trigger it's implicit animations for the `position` & `bounds` properties. To change the speed of the animation you could use:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:10.0];
_myLayer.frame = newFrame;
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Didn't do anything to the `CALayer` actually. It's basically a sublayer of ViewB's layers.

Comment: And how is viewB set up to resize in relation to viewA? Even if viewB resizes, the gradient layer shouldn't automatically resize.

Comment: Again I am not doing anything to the CALayer, yes viewB as an autosizing.

Comment: Even when viewB has autosizing, the gradient layer is not supposed to animate (relative to viewB). If it does already animate, something else is happening but that is missing from the code you posted. If you want the gradient layers frame to match the bounds of viewB you'll have to do that manually by adjusting its frame in viewB layoutSubviews for example.

Comment: Read my question carefully: `The problem with this is that the CAGradientLayer won't animate` the layer is not animating, it's just changing it's frame automatically without the animation. The ViewA is the one that is being animated...

Comment: And that's why I claim something else might be going on that is not listed in the code you posted. Because changing the frame of viewA (and thus viewB via autoresizing) should not even trigger a change of the layer frame (view/layer hierarchy separation). This also means `[UIView animateWithDuration:.....]` should basically not have any effect on layer property changes, animation wise.